# Add list to column in data frame in R, while also adding NA to the other columns

Tags: r, list, dataframe, append

I have a data frame as such:

```
>head(NameFrame)
   name  married  age
1  James Yes      34
2  Sarah No       22
3  John  Yes      55
```

And I have a list as such:

```
>head(NameList)
[1] "Kyle", "Bob"
```

How can I add this list to the data frame so that the data frame will look like this:

```
   name  married  age
1  James Yes      34
2  Sarah No       22
3  John  Yes      55 
4  Kyle  NA       NA
5  Bob   NA       NA
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

We can do like this

```
NameFrame[nrow(NameFrame) + seq_along(NameList), "name"] <- NameList
```

which gives

```
> NameFrame
   name married age
1 James     Yes  34
2 Sarah      No  22
3  John     Yes  55
4  Kyle    <NA>  NA
5   Bob    <NA>  NA
```

## data

```
> dput(NameFrame)
structure(list(name = c("James", "Sarah", "John"), married = c("Yes",
"No", "Yes"), age = c(34L, 22L, 55L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
"2", "3"))

> dput(NameList)
c("Kyle", "Bob")
```

Answer (score 1):

Also with `data.table` `rbindlist` -

```
data.table::rbindlist(list(NameFrame, data.frame(name = NameList)), fill = TRUE)

#    name married age
#1: James     Yes  34
#2: Sarah      No  22
#3:  John     Yes  55
#4:  Kyle    <NA>  NA
#5:   Bob    <NA>  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `bind_rows` which will generate the missing columns as `NA`  if we use a named `list` or `tibble/data.frame` from 'NameList' with key/column name as `name`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(NameFrame, tibble(name = NameList))
```

NOTE: Based on the values showed 'NameList' seems to be a `vector`instead of a `list`)

---

Or in `base R` with `rbind`

```
rbind(NameFrame, data.frame(name = NameList, married = NA, age = NA))
```